# Inserting a struct into an sqlite db using sqlx and rust

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-rocket, rust-sqlx

I have a question regarding inserting a data structure into a db and I can't seem to find any documentation on.

I have a data structure

```rust
#[derive(FromRow, Getters, Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
#[getset(get = "pub")]
pub struct RefreshKeys {
    id: i64,
    customer_id: i64,
    key: String,
    enabled: bool,
}
```

I want to insert this into a db with the same fields, called `refresh_keys`.

```rust
rocket_db_pools::sqlx::query_as::<_, RefreshKeys>(
  "INSERT INTO refresh_keys (id, customer_id, key, enabled)
   VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4)"
)
.fetch_one(&mut *db)
.await?
```

This sadly does not seem to work, i get the following error:

```rust
SqliteError { code: 1299, message: "NOT NULL constraint failed: refresh_keys.customer_id" }
```

I have tried for hours to find the relevant documentation, but I just can't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message you're seeing seems to indicate that the data associated with the parameters is not being passed correctly (`?1...?4`), as this would result in the values being passed as NULLs.

- Not being very familiar with SQLite, my first thought was that your parameters should be named `$1..$N`, but it looks like SQLite does allow the `?NNN` syntax per the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). So let's move on...

Next try looking closely at the query where you need to bind values to your parameters; I'm not seeing where you are passing the values to the query, for example, we could create a row of data & insert it into the database as follows. Note the `bind()` calls to bind the values from the `data` variable to the parameters in the query.

```
// Create new row to insert:
    let data = RefreshKeys {
        id: 1,
        customer_id: 1,
        key: "test".to_string(),
        enabled: true,
    };
// Now insert the row:
    let result = sqlx::query(
        "INSERT INTO refresh_keys (id, customer_id, key, enabled)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)")
        .bind(data.id)
        .bind(data.customer_id)
        .bind(data.key)
        .bind(data.enabled)
        .execute(&pool).await;
```

Without a minimal working example, it's a bit difficult to help you further, but see if the below example helps out at all.

**Working Minimal Example**

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
sqlx = { version = "0.6.3", features = ["sqlite", "macros", "runtime-tokio-rustls"] }
tokio = { version = "1.27.0", features = ["macros"] }
```

src/main.rs:

```
use sqlx::{Sqlite, SqlitePool, migrate::MigrateDatabase};

#[derive(sqlx::FromRow)]
struct RefreshKeys {
    id: i32,
    customer_id: i64,
    key: String,
    enabled: bool,
}

const DATABASE_URL: &str = "sqlite://db.sqlite";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    // Create database if not exists:
    if !Sqlite::database_exists(DATABASE_URL).await.unwrap_or(false) {
        match Sqlite::create_database(DATABASE_URL).await {
            Ok(_) => println!("Database created"),
            Err(e) => println!("Error creating database: {}", e),
        }
    } else {
        println!("Database already exists");
    }

    // Connect to database:
    let pool = SqlitePool::connect(DATABASE_URL).await.unwrap();

    // Create table (would normally do this in ./migrations/*.sql):
    let result = sqlx::query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS refresh_keys (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        key TEXT NOT NULL,
        enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL
    )").execute(&pool).await;

    match result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Table created"),
        Err(e) => println!("Error creating table: {}", e),
    }

    // Create new row to insert:
    let data = RefreshKeys {
        id: 1,
        customer_id: 1,
        key: "test".to_string(),
        enabled: true,
    };

    let result = sqlx::query(
        "INSERT INTO refresh_keys (id, customer_id, key, enabled)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)")
        .bind(data.id)
        .bind(data.customer_id)
        .bind(data.key)
        .bind(data.enabled)
        .execute(&pool).await;

    match result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Row inserted"),
        Err(e) => println!("Error inserting row: {}", e),
    }

    // Select row in database:
    let keys = sqlx::query_as::<_, RefreshKeys>(
        "SELECT * FROM refresh_keys"
        ).fetch_all(&pool).await;

    let key_vec = match keys {
        Ok(keys) => keys,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error selecting row: {}", e);
            return;
        }
    };

    for key in key_vec {
        println!("id={}, customer_id={}, key={}, enabled={}",
                 key.id,
                 key.customer_id,
                 key.key,
                 key.enabled);
    }

}
:q
```